# Efficient way to remove parts of the StringBuilder

Tags: vb.net, stringbuilder

I have a regular expression, that's search some patterns in stringbuilder:

```
Dim sb as New StringBuilder(10000) 'some long string builder, filled with text
Dim matches As MatchCollection = myRegex.Matches(sb.ToString())
```

Further, I need to remove all matches from the stringbuilder and return only start of the stringbuilder, where is only possible text, that's not matched. I know few ways to do it.

1) Remove all the rest at once:

```
Dim lenToRemove As Integer = sb.Length - matches(0).Index 
sb = sb.Remove(matches(0).Index, lenToRemove)
```

2) Replace each part with empty string in cycle:

```
For Each m As Match In matches
    sb = sb.Replace(m.Value, String.Empty) 
Next
```

3) Remove each part in cycle, backward:

```
For i As Integer = matches.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1 
    sb = sb.Remove(matches(i).Index, matches(i).Length)
Next
sb = sb.Remove(0, matches(0).Index)
```

This code is a part of some processing with millions of iterations. First two methods are working significant slower than third. E.g., 4.000.000 iterations take 101, 45, 34 seconds, respectively.

My question is why first solution is so slow? And is it possible to optimize this code?

Comment: If you remove "the end of the string" you are in fact truncating it, it may be that it just sets an internal length field to a lower value and that's it. However, when you keep stuff after the things you remove, you have to move them. Text editors that work with multi-gigabyte files tend to split the files into some form of chunks, be it line-by-line or buffers, and then work on those buffers. The chunks are allowed to be different sizes, so you don't need to adjust adjacent chunks unless your removal spans the boundaries of two such chunks.

Comment: Have you tried using a new StringBuilder and copy the parts you want to keep into it?

Comment: @AndrewMorton no, thanks for the idea, i'll check it soon.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've been checked it, and no, it's not faster, unfortunately. I still not understand why option 3 is the fastest.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen ok, thanks. Maybe it's true, and string builder keep characters in some kind of portions. That's why partially remove is works faster.

Comment: If you consider that removing parts of a string in a StringBuilder will have to move all the following characters, think about how many characters it will have to move for all sub-replacements as you consider going from the start vs. going from the end. When going from the end, you move fewer characters in average because you have already removed parts of that string.

Comment: Consider removing every second plate in a stack of dinner plates, if you start from the top and go down, by the time you remove the last plate near the bottom you only have half the stack above it that you need to lift up before removing the plate. However, if you start at the bottom you have the whole stack still present. Same thing.